# Ubuntu 20.04 Win 10 Dual boot same SSD stuck on restart

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ssd, windows-10, 20.04

I have a PC with one 256GB **SSD**
I always had only **Ubuntu 16.04** installed on this drive
When **20.04** came out, i thought i would do a dual boot with **Win 10**
As Instructed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot), I installed Win 10 first, on 100GB partition of the drive, and left the rest for Ubuntu
Then Installed **Ubuntu 20.04**, mounted `/` on the 150GB partition, and booted the first time fine
but when **restarting** the PC, i can't boot to Ubuntu any more
It stuck on the Manufacture (**Dell**) loading screen
**Win 10 boots fine**
Reinstalled several times, no change
Reinstalled **16.04, works fine**

Comment: If you selest the EFI boot menu (some key at power-up to give you a choice of boot device/OS), can you choose "ubuntu" or the disk device and boot grub?

Comment: Yeah, I get the Grub menu , and it has Ubuntu & Win, the issue happens right after choosing Ubuntu , Win works fine though

Comment: Do you have Nvidia hardware on this computer?  Maybe you need the nomodeset on the grub linux line until you install the proprietary Nvidia drivers (Additional Drivers in the app list).

Comment: Yes, I have Nvidia graphics card, and i didn't do the `nomodeset` thing, but keep in mind the i didn't dot for 16.04 also, and it works fine